# How to make randomizer randomize till it's the right number

Tags: c#, random

I'm making a sudoku game and at first I'm doing small version 3x3. After some coding I couldn't find a way to:

How do I make S randomise till its the right number (S randomizes, Skaiciai.Neradau means it didn't find a repeating number, Skaiciai.Yra_Toks_Skaicius means he found the same number already used)

EDIT: redone in English

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace _3x3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TextBox[] Boxes;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Boxes = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3};
        }

        public enum Numbers
        {
            Found_Number,
            NotFound
        };

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random X = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                int S = X.Next(1, 4);

                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        int A, B;
                        if (textBox2.Text == "") { A = 0; } else { A = int.Parse(textBox2.Text); }
                        if (textBox3.Text == "") { B = 0; } else { B = int.Parse(textBox3.Text); }
                        Numbers R = CheckIfThereIsNumber(S, new int[] { A, B });
                        if (R == Numbers.NotFound)
                        {
                            textBox1.Text = S.ToString();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        int C, D;
                        if (textBox1.Text == "") { C = 0; } else { C = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); }
                        if (textBox3.Text == "") { D = 0; } else { D = int.Parse(textBox3.Text); }
                        Numbers T = CheckIfThereIsNumber(S, new int[] { C, D });
                        if (T == Numbers.NotFound)
                        {
                            textBox2.Text = S.ToString();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        int E, F;
                        if (textBox1.Text == "") { E = 0; } else { E = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); }
                        if (textBox2.Text == "") { F = 0; } else { F = int.Parse(textBox2.Text); }
                        Numbers Y = CheckIfThereIsNumber(S, new int[] { E, F });
                        if (Y == Numbers.NotFound)
                        {
                            textBox3.Text = S.ToString();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        Numbers CheckIfThereIsNumber(int _searchednumber, int[] _numbers)
        {
            Numbers Result = Numbers.NotFound;
            for (int i = 0; i < _numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                if (_numbers[i] == _searchednumber)
                {
                    Result = Numbers.Found_Number;
                }
            }
            return Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard enough trying to look at code that isn't in this site's preferred language without adding code formatting issues to it. Please clean up your code.

Comment: Yeah i could do that

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Contrary to itsme86's comment, there is no preferred language here. If a computer speaks it, the community does, just label your question with the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way would be to not randomize numbers themselves, but to make a list of unused numbers and shuffle which number from the list will you take.

```
List<int> notUsed = findUnusedNumbers();

while (notUsed.Count) {
    int randomIndex = X.Next(0, notUsed.Count);
    int myChosenNumber = notUsed.get(randomIndex);
    // do something with the number here
    notUsed.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
}
```

Comment: the problem is that it's for a programing starter school and we didn't learn List and RemoveAt

Comment: @TheNoahie
You can fake it with arrays though, after you randomize the index, create a new array without that index with a loop.
But probably learning Lists a little faster is not a bad idea :)

Comment: I found other way, but it's not so efficienty so I'll try to learn list (I just used another for so it would run through 10 times)

Comment: It should be strongly noted that the reason why you should use a loop and  list of unused numbers is because if you just keep picking random numbers, you could keep randomly picking 1 forever.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even using random numbers here at all?

I've done a Sudoku solver before, no random numbers whatsoever.  You want to iterate over the possibilities, not choose randomly.

Given that you said you haven't been taught those list operations, if you have to use random numbers simply keep trying until you get a valid one.